# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the ResultSet object is closed

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to run StoredProcedure using jtds.
My database is on SQL SErver 2008

```
private String DRIVER_NAME_VALUE = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";  
private String URL_VALUE = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"; 
...
cstmt =dbConnection.getCallableStatement("{? = call dbo.GetAgentStats (?)}");
.
.
.
rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
```

when trying to go over the Result set I got the Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the ResultSet object is closed.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.checkOpen(JtdsResultSet.java:299)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.first(JtdsResultSet.java:527)
        at com.verint.impact360.WFM_plugins.CCE.CCEASCMAdapter.runReport(CCEASCMAdapter.java:238)
        at com.verint.impact360.WFM_plugins.CCE.CCEASCMAdapter.retrieveData(CCEASCMAdapter.java:131)
        at com.bluepumpkin.Plugins.PTeXtender.GenericDCSPlugin.retrieveStatisticsData(GenericDCSPlugin.java:332)
        at com.bluepumpkin.Plugins.PTeXtender.GenericDCSPlugin.start(GenericDCSPlugin.java:68)
        at com.verint.impact360.WFM_plugins.CCE.CCEASCMAdapter.main(CCEASCMAdapter.java:75)
Logger.logStackTrace():----- End Stack Trace   ------
```

Is it related to SQL Server 2008?
I am not sure ,but I didn't have this error when connectig to SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can only iterate over the `ResultSet` when it has not already been closed by calling `close()` on `ResultSet`, `Statement` and/or `Connection`.

If your actual intent is to pass the content of the `ResultSet` out of the scope of the method where it is been created, then you should be mapping this to a `List<SomeObject>` first and then return it instead. Or if your actual intent is to pass it to some other class/method which expects a `ResultSet` as argument (which is by its own a poor design, but that aside), then you should be doing that inside the very same `try` block as the `ResultSet` is been created.

Comment: Thanks,this is no thte situation here, I want to go over it directly after runnng executeQuery.

Comment: If this happens inside the try block then there's either a bug in the JDBC driver or there's something seriously wrong in the code design such as having `ResultSet` declared as class variable instead of as local method variable (and thus being shared among all threads). Try to investigate if the JDBC code is written as per the normal JDBC idiom.

Comment: @BalusC Why do you say it is a poor design to pass a ResultSet as argument ?

Comment: @Hern: this implies that you need to keep the connection open in order to be able to use its resultset outside the method and that there's no clean way to close the connection after the use of the resultset. In other words: resource leaking. Your app would break after several hours of running.

Comment: @BalusC I thought that once a ResultSet is read, then it didn't depend on the connection, seems wrong, I will check JDBC doc, thanks

Comment: @BalusC what about a method like this to "fill" an object from DB:

`private void fillFromDB(ResultSet rs) {
                this.setPropertyA(rs.getString("fieldA"));
                this.setPropertyB(rs.getString("fieldB"));    
                ...
}` doesn't worth the use of ResultSet as argument? what do you think? thanks

Comment: @Hern: It doesn't matter as long as the resultset is been closed in the finally block of the very same try block where it is been created. You can perfectly refactor the resultset->javabean mapping in a private method as long as you close it properly afterwards.